# How to add a comment on an index in a Laravel migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, indexing, database-migration

In my Laravel 9 application with a MySQL database, I am trying to add a comment to a unique contraint with a migration file. According to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-modifiers:%7E:text=%2D%3Ecomment(%27my%20comment%27)) adding comments is only allowed on column modifiers (thus no support for the unique constraint). However, when I look at the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#:%7E:text=for%20more%20information.-,COMMENT%20%27string%27,-Index%20definitions%20can) I see MySQL does support it.

My following code will silently ignore the comment on the unique constraint:

```
Schema::create('customer_order', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedInteger('customer_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('order_id');

    $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customer');
    $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders');
    $table->unique(['customer_id'])->comment('To enforce this is table is used as a one to many relationship.');
    $table->unique(['customer_id', 'order_id']);
}
```

Since it appears that Laravel does not support adding comments on indexes (like a unique constraint), is there a workaround?

p.s. I am aware I strictly do not need a pivot table in this situation. Please just assume I need the pivot table setup for some historical or technical reason.

Comment: You can run raw SQL inside of Migrations, so if `->comment()` doesn't work, just do something like `DB::statement('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ...')` (following the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: A `UNIQUE` index belongs to the _table_.  It contains one or more columns.